# How to create a theme date view with CSS styles?

Tags: views, theming, 8, datetime

I created my view (datev) that contains two field (date and description).
I renamed my template views-view-datev.html.twig and views-view-fields--datev---block.html.twig.
I already have my CSS but I do not know how to use my template theme.

> [image: screenshot]

I want it appears like this.
[image]

Comment: what result are you currently getting?

Comment: the resultat is :  2016-03-01 Return to the line description

Comment: I have my CSS to achieve this poster but I do not know how to add ?? how broken down the date for this display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have my CSS to achieve this poster but I do not know how to add ??
> how broken down the date for this display

Add 1 more Content: Even Date field.

Then for each Even Date field, select custom formatter.

for the first one put `d` (Note: there seems to be a bug, you will have to do this twice, as when you save the 1st time it does not change)

[image]

for the second one put `F Y` (Note: there seems to be a bug, you will have to do this twice, as when you save the 1st time it does not change)

[image]

#### Result

[image]

**PS:** You can add CSS classes to your field under the fields STYLE SETTINGS, no need to use template files to add css classes.

[image]

Then, for example, you add `.cool { border: solid red; }` to your theme's css file.

Comment: I create content type(Event)contains field Event date(date) and field body(text)and I create my views.How to update this for broken down the date for this display? I don't understand!!

Comment: @sony updated my answer with pictures, I hope you get it now.

Comment: I have another problem, I would be glad if you help me

Comment: @Sony what is it?

Comment: How to create Slideshow carousel in Drupal8?
I installed Slideshow module and I created my views with my content(photos)I created my view "sliderv" with a field containing several pictures; I reused the view "views-view-Unformatted-sliderv-block-1.html.twig". I already have my CSS and JavaScript,but it's still not work.

Thanks!

Comment: @sony, that's a totally different question which is not related to this one. Please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark ✓ and create a new question for the other one, thx.

Comment: I need your help, how to add a date period like in my publication , for some  dates, not all dates ,Thank you darling